# Why does Kotlin JDK8 also include Kotlin JDK7 on the classpath?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin to build a web service and I stumbled upon what I consider to be a strange curiosity. With this build.gradle:

```
group 'com.example'
version '0.1.0'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.2.71'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion"
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

I get this error during compilation:

```
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    .../kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.2.71.jar (version 1.2)
    .../kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.jar (version 1.2)
    .../kotlin-reflect-1.3.10.jar (version 1.3)
    .../kotlin-stdlib-1.3.10.jar (version 1.3)
    .../kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.10.jar (version 1.3)
```

OK, no problem, `jackson-module-kotlin` is pulling in the kotlin 1.3 dependencies. I can exclude them. But the bit that caught my attention was the second line. `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` is also pulling in `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`. In fact, I can exclude it and everything still runs as expected:

```
compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion") {
    exclude group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", module: "kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
}
```

Why is `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` pulling onto my classpath the seemingly unnecessary `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`?

Comment: I believe they just included java 8 specific stuff in the jdk8 dependency, leaving all the java 7+ stuff in the jdk7 one. So you need both to have the whole stdlib. I imagine you also get the common stdlib, don't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning you see during the compilation happens because `jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8` dependency apparently brings `kotlin-stdlib:1.3.10` into the classpath and that version overrides your declared dependency on 1.2.71. To avoid warning you should either migrate your project to Kotlin 1.3.x or downgrade `jackson-module-kotlin` dependency to some previous version which depends on Kotlin 1.2.x.

`kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` is an addition on top of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`, and the latter is addition on top of `kotlin-stdlib`. You should not exclude these transitive dependencies, otherwise you might get runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks. "`kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` is an addition on top of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`, and the latter is addition on top of `kotlin-stdlib`" was the answer I am looking for. As I mentioned in my question, I'm aware that `jackson-module-kotlin` was the cause of the errors.

Comment: Note that if `jackson-module-kotlin` used some new functions added in Kotlin 1.3, it wouldn't work with Kotlin 1.2.x dependency in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The `kotlin-stdlib-common`, `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`, and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` seem to be mutually exclusive from what I could see inside the jars. That's why you need the jdk7 artifact even if you use the jdk8.

The `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` jar only contains things that were added in JDK7 like `AutoCloseable` and other internal apis. This is not included in the JDK8 artifact, which only include things added in JDK8.

If you don't use the `use` or `closeFinally` global functions, your code should work fine without the jdk7 artifact, but there is no real reason to exclude this jar IMHO.